# Usage of Leaflet with Ionic2 typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, leaflet, ionic2

I'm new to **Ionic2** and **Angular2** with **typescript** and I want to build a mobile application for iOS and Android. As a next step I want to include a map and found **Leaflet**, to change easily between GoogleMaps and OSM, ...

So, my problems started with installing: There are different packages like `npm install leaflet` or `npm install leaflet-map` or `npm install ui-leaflet` and many more..

Second, I have no idea how to include those packages then. Would be great, if someone could provide me a really simple basic app in Ionic2 showing a leaflet-map.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ok..
First install leaflet and its typings

```
npm install leaflet --save
npm install @types/leaflet --save
```

Then import **leaflet** to your Component or whatever with

```
import 'leaflet';
```

In the html-file add a div with `id="map"` and a pre-set size (better do it via css).

```
<div style="height: 180px" id="map"></div>
```

As `styleUrls: []` is still buggy in Ionic2, you also have to add the leaflet styles to your html-file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
```

After this preparing you can start with the [leaflet tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/) like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   var map = L.map('map')
      .setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

   L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets-basic/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
      maxZoom: 18,
      accessToken: 'xxx'
    }).addTo(this.map);

}
```

Comment: Can you please post your code somewhere? I am upgrading to ionic1 with my leaflet app and trying to wrap my head around it. Cheers!

Comment: These lines are all the **ionic 2** related lines. Everything else should be equal to your already existing code. Like adding markers and so on. But feel free to ask.

Comment: Got it running. Thanks. However, I have a problem with loading the map tiles. They sparsely appear with empty gaps and the handling of the map like zooming does not help. Running it smoothly was possible through the `https://github.com/tsubik/ionic2-geofence` code, but starting from the blank template it provides this clunky UX. Any idea?

Comment: Are you using the `tileLayer` correctly? I added it to the solution above.

Comment: `Leaflet.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png").addTo(this.map);`

Comment: I just tried your code and get an error `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`. When I google it, it says that there is a problem with the certificate of the server, in your case osm.. No idea if it's true, but give mapbox.com a try.

Comment: Changed to http, no secure. Still same error for the same request that works with Ionic1 and Leaflet0.7.7 instead of the current 1.0.2 npm downloaded automatically? Should I try older versions of Leaflet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129289/discussion-between-el-dude-and-sos).

Comment: My mistake was I didn't have the 1.0.2 css file in index. Fixed now. However, is there a way to link to the css in the module installed thru npm?