# Ionic 2 / Leaflet blank map on Android device

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic2, leaflet

I'm trying to load a leaflet map on Ionic 2 page and everything seems to work perfectly in the browser when running "ionic serve". The problem is that when I try to run the project on a real Android device with "ionic run android", the map component load with blank background so that the OSM and Google tilelayers aren't loading.

I followed this answer: [Usage of Leaflet with Ionic2 typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40020230/2669096)
 and the error still remains.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked your white list? You can easily check if you can load external static assets from the Tile Servers by adding an image with source to a given tile, e.g. `<img src="https://tile.openstreetmap.org/0/0/0.png" />`. You can also use the Chrome remote debugging tool to inspect for potential network errors.

Comment: Thanks man it was the whitelist plugin who is missing.
i just installed that plugin and it worked like a sharm. thanks again  :)